# JQuery countdown timer plug in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some html below and wish to insert a countdown timer to NYE where it currently says X, Y and Z.

I'm having some problems doing this as I do not understand the process required. There seems to be plenty of examples on-line, however they seem to require a plugin(?). I wish to do this simply with JQuery.

```
<div class='countdown hidden-xs' style='color: #fff; widht:100%; height:35px; background-color: #CB3544; padding-top:8px' > <span class='' style=' font-size:17px;   border-radius: 5px; padding:3px 5px; margin: 0 15%; color: red; background-color:#fff' > SALE NOW ON </span> <span class='' style='padding: 0px 20px' >Time to NYE: X DAYS Y MINUTES Z SECONDS </span>  </div>
```

Can anybody please help on the steps needed to proceed?

Comment: Make use of Date($.now()) and subtract it from new year.  tbh best example of how to so it will be the plugins as if its a jquery plugin its probably doing something similar already

Comment: Have a look at `setInterval`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval if you can calculate the x,y,z then put it in a function and call it with `setInterval`